# Nós precisamos falar sobre a tag programação

Tags: debate, tags, meta-tags

Me deparei hoje com uma pergunta com a tag [programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o), e aí descobri que existem 19 perguntas com a tag. Todas as perguntas são desse ano, 8 apenas neste mês. Parece que ela está ganhando popularidade, ou que alguém parou de fazer uma limpeza que era feita antes. Alguém acha que esta tag tem alguma utilidade?

Apesar de o SOpt ter algumas perguntas que não sejam sobre programação, é bem óbvio que a grande maioria é, e colocar a tag não ajuda em nada. Para mim, esta tag é tão útil quanto seriam as tags [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pergunta) ou [dúvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d%c3%bavida) (não se preocupem, elas não existem!).

Acho que deveríamos enviá-la para o limbo das tags mortas. O que acham?

Comment: Concordo, demasiado genérica. A meu ver é remover.

Comment: É meio irônico uma tag `Programação` num site sobre programação, sou a favor de matar a tag.

Comment: Tem um monte deste tipo.

Comment: Quando vi essa postagem, não acreditei, realmente é desnecessária, seria bom quando _vocês_ vissem uma dessas remover.

Comment: Pode remover, afinal é redundante.

Comment: Remover (neste caso) é fácil, todas já foram. Mas acho que é importante eliminar a tag em si para que não seja usada ou criada novamente, para evitar acúmulo de tags desnecessárias e o pior dos casos, que são perguntas apenas com esta tag e que dificilmente são vistas.

Comment: @Molx Ela é apagada na madrugada quando não tem perguntas com ela

Comment: Concordo também sobre ser redundante.

Comment: A comunidade já é bem específica mesmo. É uma tag desnecessária